# Добавление класса при hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Вот моя беда:
http://jsfiddle.net/EzHaw/1/

Вот там если навести на пункт меню, он становится красным. Если навести на "Каталог", то выпадает меню. Но если уже наводить на подпункты, то родитель перестает быть красным. А мне надо сохранить ховер.

Там из кода первая часть - меню, а вторая - то, как я мыслил. Там, к сожалению, применяется ко всем пунктам меню (поймете, как посмотрите). Я еще пытался `children, parent` использовать, все никак.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

P.S. Если можно объединить 2 кода - пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *Если навести на "Каталог", то выпадает меню*, увы и ах... не выпадает :)

Comment: Ах да. jQuery только начинаю учить. Отсюда непрофессиональность. А на счет кривости вывода - не обращайте внимания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо Вам надо что то типа такого:

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu li').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('menuhover');
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    },
                        function(){
                            $(this).find('ul').hide();
                            $(this).removeClass('menuhover');
                        });

});
```

Пляшите от переменной $(this) - избегайте явных указаний если работаете со множествами, а хотите изменить конкретику.

Comment: А я и с this пытался. Не вышло. Ваше работает. Спасибо большое

Comment: @Чад Есть небольшая проблемка. Когда отводишь, цвет меняется на красный, хотя в классе задан белый

Comment: а не, все вышло. Спасибо